# Yocto: How to decide SRC_URI value based on two option values

Tags: yocto

I have this yocto recipe for a package, where I have feature A and sub-features AA and AB. All these (feature and sub-features) have their own enable flag on the image configuration file.
Since they can all be independently enabled, how can I guarantee that sub-features are only considered if the main feature is also enabled?

```
PACKAGECONFIG_append = "${@bb.utils.contains('A', 'y', ' a_is_enabled', '', d)}"
PACKAGECONFIG[a_is_enabled] = "-DENABLE_FEATURE_A=ON,-DENABLE_FEATURE_A=OFF,,"

SRC_URI += "${@bb.utils.contains('A', 'y', 'file://files_for_A', '', d)}"

SRC_URI += "${@bb.utils.contains('AA', 'y', 'file://files_for_AA', '', d)}"

SRC_URI += "${@bb.utils.contains('AB', 'y', 'file://files_for_AB', '', d)}"
```

This is a failsafe in case the image configuration file is messed up!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In order to make `AA` or `AB` dependent on `A`, create a temporary variable

```
EVAL_AA = "${@bb.utils.contains('AA', 'y', 'file://files_for_AA', '', d)}"
```

then, through immediate variable expansion:

```
SRC_URI_append := "${@bb.utils.contains('A', 'y', '${EVAL_AA}', '', d)}"
```

if `AB` depends on `AA` being enabled:

```
EVAL_AB = "${@bb.utils.contains('AB', 'y', 'file://files_for_AB', '', d)}"
EVAL_AB := "${@bb.utils.contains('AA', 'y', '${EVAL_AB}', '', d)}"
SRC_URI_append := "${@bb.utils.contains('A', 'y', '${EVAL_AB}', '', d)}"
```

Not pretty but it works!
Is this the way? Or... There is one which is prettier or easier?